# Slider duplicated in header

Tags: jquery, css, html

My site has a slider located towards the middle of the page, and it shows up properly, but it also shows a duplicate slider on the top. What's going on? My site is at http://jcwebandgraphic.com/ if you load the page and wait for a second, you'll see the duplicate slider at the top.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en-us'>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'/>
        <title>Homepage | JC Web and Graphic</title>
        <link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='images/favicon.png'/>
        <meta name='keywords' content='jc web and graphic, web designer, graphic designer, web design, graphic          design, cheap, inexpensive, affordable, awesome, beautiful, vancouver washington, portland oregon,          hotspot, host, hosting, domain, domains, domain registration, cheap, affordable'>
        <meta name='description' content='Web and Graphic Design, Hosting, Domains, and more!'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styles.css'>

        <script src='jquery-awesomeness.js'></script>

        <!-- Slider Link -->
        <script src='responsiveslides.min.js'></script>

        <script>
            // Slider Functions
            $(function() {
                $('.rslides').responsiveSlides({
                    speed: 1200,
                    timeout: 3000
                });
            });

            //Google Analytics
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

            ga('create', 'UA-52983504-1', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>
    </head>



    <body>
        <!-- header -->
        <header id='home'>
            <div id='logo'>
                <img src='images/logo-1000.png'>
            </div>
        </header>



        <!-- nav -->
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#home'>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href='#portfolio'>Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href='#table'>Pricing</a></li>
                <li><a href='#contact'>Contact</a></li>
                <br>
                <!--
                    <li><a href='#blog'>Blog</a></li>
                -->
            </ul>
        </nav>



        <!-- section 1 home -->             
        <section id='welcome'>
            <div class='content c2'>
                <h2>Welcome!</h2>
                <p>
                    We're a powerful little design house based in the beautiful Pacific Northwest. We specialize in web & graphic design, web hosting, and so much more. Our sophisticated aesthetic and versatile designs are perfect for the modern web, printing, and signage. 
                </p>
            </div>
        </section>



        <!-- section 2 portfolio -->        
        <section id='portfolio'>
            <div class='c1'>
                <h2>Projects</h2>
                <div id='slider'>
                    <ul class='rslides'>
                        <li><a href='audioinformationradio.com'><img src='images/air.jpg' alt='Professional Project: Audio Information Radio'></a></li>

                        <li><a href='danachapmanmassage.com'><img src='images/dana.jpg' alt='Professional Project: Dana Chapman Massage'></a></li>

                        <li><a href='http://dtc-wsuv.org/jcohen/zavaah/'><img src='images/zavaah.jpg' alt='Student Project: Zava&apos;ah, An Ethical Will'></a></li>

                        <li><a href='http://dtc-wsuv.org/jcohen/howto/'><img src='images/crash.jpg' alt='Student Project: A Crash Course in Chemistry'></a></li>

                        <li><a href='http://dtc-wsuv.org/jcohen/tools-for-ethical-decision-making/'><img src='images/ethics.jpg' alt='Student Project: Tools for Ethical Dilemmas'></a></li>

                        <li><a href='http://dtc-wsuv.org/jcohen/placestory/'><img src='images/placestory.jpg' alt='Student Project: This is Me'></a></li>

                        <li><a href='http://dtc-wsuv.org/jcohen/blackbird/'><img src='images/bird.jpg' alt='Student Project: 13 Ways of Looking at a Blackbird'></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>



<!-- section 3 pricing -->      
        <section id='table'>
            <div class='content c1'>
                <h2>Pricing</h2>
                <table>
                    <th>DESIGN</th>
                    <th>Essentials</th>
                    <th>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Single Page</td>
                        <td>Starting at $100</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Multi-Page</td>
                        <td>Starting at $300</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Multi-Device</td>
                        <td>Starting at $800</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Logo</td>
                        <td>Starting at $200</td>
                    </td>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Branding</td>
                        <td>Starting at $1000</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Consults &amp Updates</td>
                        <td>Starting at $50</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Specialty Pricing</td>
                        <td>Dependent on Project</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br><br><br>
                <table>
                        <th>HOSTING</th>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Complete Package + 500MB</td>
                        <td>$100 per Year</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Additional Disk Space</td>
                        <td>$15 per 100MB</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Domain Transfer</td>
                        <td>Starting at $50</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Domain Registration</td>
                        <td>$20</td>
                    </tr>   
                    <tr>
                        <td>SSL Certificate</td>
                        <td>$50</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </section>



<!-- section 4 contact -->      
        <section id='contact'>
            <div class='content c2'>
                <h2>Contact</h2>
                <p>Phone: 
                    <a href='callto:+13602810359'>360-241-6742
                    </a>
                </p>
                <address style='font-style: normal;'>Email: 
                    <a href='mailto:admin@jcwebandgraphic.com'>
                        admin@jcwebandgraphic.com
                    </a>
                </address>
                <div id='contactform'>
                    <form action='contact.php' method='post'>
                        Your name:
                        <input class='type' type='text' name='cf_name'>
                        <br>
                        Your e-mail:
                        <input class='type' type='text' name='cf_email'>
                        <br>
                        Message
                        <textarea name='cf_message'></textarea>
                        <input class='button' type='submit' value='Send'>
                        <input class='button' type='reset' value='Clear'>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>



<!-- footer -->             
        <footer>
            <a id='resume' href='resume.pdf' target='_blank'>Download Resume</a>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/* ==============================        CSS Styles for JC Web and Graphic        ============================== */
/* 
    This is the intellectual property of JC Web and Graphic. All Rights Reserved.
*/






/* ==============================                   Basic Reset                   ============================== */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    }



/* ==============================                Begin CSS Styles                 ============================== */

/* ==============================                  Web Font Kits                  ============================== */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'bebasregular';
    src: url('fonts/bebas/bebas___-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/bebas/bebas___-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/bebas/bebas___-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/bebas/bebas___-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    }

@font-face {
    font-family: 'champagne__limousinesregular';
    src: url('fonts/champagne/champagne__limousines-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/champagne/champagne__limousines-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/champagne/champagne__limousines-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/champagne/champagne__limousines-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/champagne/champagne__limousines-webfont.svg#champagne__limousinesregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    }

@font-face {
    font-family: 'hingeregular';
    src: url('fonts/hinge/hinge-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/hinge/hinge-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/hinge/hinge-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/hinge/hinge-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/hinge/hinge-webfont.svg#hingeregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    }



/* ==============================                Structural Styles                ============================== */
footer {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #403833;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    z-index: 100;
    }



/* ==============================                    Nav Styles                   ============================== */
nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    right: 2%;
    padding: 15px;
    z-index: 500;
    }

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    }

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'bebasregular';
    font-size: .75em;
    letter-spacing: .25em;
    }

a:hover {
    color: #efb40f;
    }

/* ==============================                   Main Content                  ============================== */
#logo {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    }

#logo img {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 5% 30%;
    }

#resume {
    margin: 15px;
    color: #dddddd;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
    }

.content {
    font-family: 'hingeregular';
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    }

.c1 {
    width: 70%;
    padding: 10% 15%;
    }

.c2 {
    width: 60%;
    padding: 10% 20%;
    line-height: 3em;
    }

#welcome {
    background-color: #13A3A5; 
    }

#portfolio {
    background-color: #F2F2EF;
    }

#table {
    background-color: #DBC390;
    }

#contact {
    background-color: #459950;
    }

/* #pricing */
#table td {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    }

#table th {
    color: #949494;
    }

/* #contact */
form {
    margin: 50px;
    font-size: .75em;
    }

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    color: #949494;
    text-align: left;
    }

.type {
    color: #949494;
    }

.button {
    padding: .5em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    background-color: #5BD9AB;
    border: none;
    border-radius: .2em;
    }

.button:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #5BD9AB;
    }

/* ==============================                Typographic Styles               ============================== */
h2 {
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    font-family: 'champagne__limousinesregular';
    font-size: 2em;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    text-align: right;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    }



/* ==============================                  RSlides Styles                 ==============================*/
#slider {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    }

.rslides {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 5;
    }

.rslides li {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    }

.rslides img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    z-index: 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your slides are absolutely positioned but your encasing div needs a relative position so as to not have the absolutely positioned slides jump out of them. Simply add a position:relative; to your #slider

```
#slider{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: :) Glad it helped. Would you mind marking it as answered then?